# Cannot use PHP sem_get() function in my host

Tags: php, linux, apache, mutex, dreamhost

I want to use semaphores in my PHP code. I **updated** the PHP version of my server and it works fine **via command-line**. When I try to access it **via browser** it gives me the error :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function sem_get() in .../semaphore.php on line 8
```

Here is the code :

```
<?php
$key = 123567;
$maxAcquire = 1;
$permissions = 0666;
$autoRelease = 1;

//it gives the error on the line below
$semaphore = sem_get($key, $maxAcquire, $permissions, $autoRelease);
sem_acquire($semaphore); 
echo "hello world!";
sem_release($semaphore);
?>
```

Even though it works via command-line, why doesn't it work on browser? Is it about **apache server**? Do you have any suggestions about *mutex* on PHP other than *semaphores*? I want the text, on database, to be edited by one user at a time. Thank you.

Comment: It isn't mandatory to have the same configuration for the same PHP environments (command-line, Apache module, CGI...). You need to install the extension for command-line.

Answer (score 0):

The [installation note](http://php.net/manual/en/sem.installation.php) mentions:

> Support for this functions are not enabled by default. To enable System V semaphore support compile PHP with the option --enable-sysvsem . To enable the System V shared memory support compile PHP with the option --enable-sysvshm . To enable the System V messages support compile PHP with the option --enable-sysvmsg .

You have compile PHP with `--enable-sysvsem` to enable the function.

Last, you can verify the status of the semaphore support using `phpinfo()` function.

---

**UPDATE** Additionally, OP discovered that Apache is using different version than the PHP version used in console. Therefore, the output from browser and console are different.

Comment: I compiled my custom PHP with `--enable-sysvsem` and it works when I run the code via command-line: `php semaphore.php`. When I type `php -v` to the command-line I see that the php version is also updated. But it does not work on browser.

Comment: Next thing to do is to confirm the PHP used by Apache is the same build as the PHP used by Terminal. Also, still recommend you to check `phpinfo()` in browser.

Comment: PHP version on my **apache server** is different! Do you know how may I change it? Thanks for your interest, by the way.

Comment: To know how to resolve this issue, first I have to know which Linux distribution & version you're using.

Comment: The host is running Debian Wheezy.

Comment: The status of the semaphore support in phpinfo() function "--enable-sysvsem=shared" by the way.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Try [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/50344/how-to-have-two-version-of-php-installed-and-switch-easily)

Comment: Thank you. I will mark it as answer if I can solve it like this.